# ¿Cómo puedo crear un triqui en PHP en el cual 2 letras X y 3 letras O aparezcan aleatoriamente por el tablero y no se repitan?

Tags: php

Debo realizar una matriz de 3 X 3 donde la letra X sea color Azul y la letra O color Rojo, deben aparecer al azar 3 letras O y 2 letras X. El problema es que no sé el cómo hacer para que $a y $b no tomen los mismos valores que las demás variables. Aquí algo de lo que he adelantado y el error que quiero evitar está en la imagen.

```
<?php


$a = rand(0,2);//primera x
$b = rand(0,2);
$c = rand(0,2);//segunda x
$d = rand(0,2);

$x = rand(0,2);//primer o
$y = rand(0,2);

$tablero[0] = array();
$tablero[1] = array();
$tablero[2] = array();

$o = "<img src='https://png.vector.me/files/images/3/3/337022/blue_circle_preview' width = '100px' height='100px' <br>";
$x = "<img src='https://icones.pro/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/icone-x-rouge.png' width = '100px' height='100px' <br>";
$cuadrovacio="<img src='https://www.arguments.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/cuadro-blanco.png' width = '100px' height='100px' <br>";

echo "<table border='1' style='border-color:green'>";

for ($i = 0; $i <= 2 ; $i++){
    
    echo "<tr>";
    
    for($j = 0; $j <= 2 ; $j++){
        
        $tablero[$i][$j]=$cuadrovacio;
           
            if($i==$x && $j==$y){ 

                $tablero[$i][$j]=$x;
                
        }   
        
        if($i==$c && $j==$d ){ //segunda X

               if ($c != $a && $d != $b){
                   
                   $tablero[$i][$j]=$x;
                   
               } 
                
        } 
        
        echo "<td>".$tablero[$i][$j]."</td>";
        
    }
    
    echo "</tr>";
    
}
```

?>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado hasta ahora? Aquí no te vamos a hacer la tarea.

Comment: jajaja, perdón, no fui claro. Mí pregunta va orientada al cómo puedo poner una X en un array aleatoriamente, no sé si debo hacer una condición o algo parecido (soy principiante en esto)